# Using WebDeploy with an Azure node website doesn't trigger npm install

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, continuous-integration, webdeploy

I am using WebDeploy to deploy a node website to azure.
I've seen in samples and demos that it should trigger a `npm install` on deploy. 
But it is not. I've also seen almost every demo uses git deployment.
Is automatic `npm install` not supported for WebDeploy or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it a simple express based node Web app.? Direct publish using visual Studio should work.

Comment: It isn't a Visual Studio solution, it's simply a express web app. I just want to run `npm install` on azure webdeploy.

Comment: my deploy script runs on a CI server

Comment: Hmm I have used teamcity CI with a project that uses node,npm primarily for gulp. It's not a node website though. But one of the build step is an npm install. And I deploy to azure Web app (website previously)

Comment: do you deploy the node_modules folder to azure?

Comment: I don't since I use azure websites and it supports package.json based installation. But as per this article there may be issues with some modules and you may have to deploy the node modules folder. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use WebDeploy, it will just copy over all the file from your machine to cloud, it will not trigger any build process. You will have to responsible to make sure your app is ready to run.

if you want CI function, please setup continues deployment, here is tutorial for setting up local git
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

and there are other options if you have repository in github/bitbucket/Visual studio Team Service etc ... (go to https://portal.azure.com, select your site --> all settings --> continuous deployment   to see all supported optinos)

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc [Publish to Microsoft Azure Website using Web Deploy](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Publish-to-Azure-Website-using-Web-Deploy), it said

> Deployment will include all the files in your project. Files in the node_modules folder are included automatically, even if they are not part of the project.

So all files under your project folder in VS, including the node_modules folder, will be deployed.